# How did Jesus manage to remain sinless?

Tags: life-of-jesus, sin, christology, temptation

In his 33 years of life, He never sinned. I know I didn’t make it that far before sinning; nobody but Him could or can.

So how did He do it? he was probably tempted to sin, but He didn’t.

Comment: Various denominations would have different answers to this question, so you'd need to specify whose answers you want.

Comment: @moonman239-I have taken the liberty to edit your very important Question. It has implications for Believers in their struggle to keep from sinning.  As well, it touches on the Deity and essence of Jesus personhood. You have raised an important issue. Feel free to revert back to your "closed" question wording if this edit is foreign to your intent in questioning.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a Trinitarian answer.  Jehovah's Witnesses, Unitarian, or LDS (Latter Day Saints) will have a different answer, so I will edit / delete this answer when scope is added to the Question.

---

#### Trinitarian answer

Jesus managed to remain sinless because his human nature is "full of grace and truth" (John 1:14b), possible because **he was first God's *Logos* (John 1:1-2) who "became flesh" (John 1:14a)**, meaning that God's essence took on human form in the person of Jesus.  Jesus as God is of course sinless, and because the grace of Jesus as God (i.e. the *Logos*) flows in full to Jesus's human nature.  Jesus's human nature empowered by the full grace of the Holy Spirit was then **capable** of being sinless, meaning that Jesus had the perfect will to conform to God's goodness at all times while on earth.

But our will is not as perfect, being marred by the Fall; our psychology is messed up since birth.  Although Jesus DID face all kinds of temptations that we also face (including high spiritual temptation recounted in Matt 4:1-11) he didn't succumb into sin, even when at the prospect of crucifixion he was tempted to withdraw from fulfilling His mission to save us on the cross (Matt 26:36-46).  For this reason Jesus was deemed fit by God to save us if we are at least **WILLING to be united with Jesus** through faith, enabling Jesus's divine life to help us fix our brokenness.

For more on this, hear the segment "Could Christ have sinned" from the Church Grammar interview with Fr. Thomas Joseph White on [Tough Christology Questions](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/thomas-joseph-white-on-tough-christology-questions/id1449161376?i=1000545220691) minutes 19:50 - 25:28.

P.S. It's wrong to say that Jesus is "half-God".  Most Christians see Jesus as fully God and fully Man, according to [Chalcedonian Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Definition).

Comment: **Fully God!** Jesus was indeed fully God. But He took off His royal robes and laid aside His crown, to be clothed with flesh on Earth. (Hebrew 1) He never ceased to have a "relationship" with the divine Father while on Earth, and by wholly "doing what He saw the Father do," He never sinned, though experiencing temptations we mortals also face.

Answer (score -3):

Being half-God could have give him a unique ability to resist sin that us mere mortals do not have.

This one-sentence comment provides the start of a new answer.  Anne

Comment: Which denomination teaches that he was *half* God?

Comment: Just to say that evidence is required for assertions. One sentence is almost never going to give a proper answer on this site! You have really just made a comment, so if you could provide theological points (and also deal with curiousdannii's valid question!) that would prevent your answer being removed.